# Use PHP function return value from onSubmit as a variable within in action for an HTML Form

Tags: php, html, forms, action, onsubmit

So I have something like this (barebone for simplicity of the question):

```
<?php
    $paymentResult = 'Unknown';
    function processPayment(){
        // Process all payment values from form1 and retrieve the result of the transaction.
        $GLOBALS['paymentResult'] = 'Your payment was completed successfully!';
    }
?>                  

<form name="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="return processPayment();" action="<?php echo 'checkout_s.php?result=' . $paymentResult; ?>">
    <!--Additional Credit Card Payment Controls-->
    <input type="submit" value="Process Payment">
</form>
```

The `processPayment()` method obviously has additional messages and logic in case the payment fails and etc.

My question is, no matter what I set `$paymentResult` to within the `processPayment()` function, it always passes 'Unknown' as the value of 
 the post variable when I echo `$_REQUEST['result'];` on checkout_s.php.

I'm pretty confident I'm using the global variable correctly.  Can somebody please offer advice on how to correctly modify the code or offer an additional method?  I don't want to pass credit card information as post variables, so I'm processing it on the same page.  All I want to do is pass the result of the transaction to the action page.

Comment: Did you actually name your javascript and PHP function with the same name, or are you confusing client-side and server-side code and assume that `onsubmit="return processPayment() "` will somehow trigger a PHP function?

Comment: Yes, they are the same names.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is something wrong in your `onsubmit`. The value on `onsubmit` should be about javascript, but you put `processPayment()` php function in it.

PHP function should be inside the php declaration. Change the  `onsubmit` value into this.

```
onsubmit="return <?php processPayment(); echo $paymentResult; ?>;"
```

Comment: Ahhh, so stupid.  Sometimes one just needs another set of eyes. Thank you, David.

Comment: glad that i can help. sometimes tiny mistake goes unnoticed.